# Is it possible to add or remove to a list based on a bool value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following `bool`

```
bool showJustify = false;
```

and I have the following list:

```
    final _valueToText = <Attribute, String>{
      Attribute.leftAlignment: Attribute.leftAlignment.value!,
      Attribute.centerAlignment: Attribute.centerAlignment.value!,
      Attribute.rightAlignment: Attribute.rightAlignment.value!,
      Attribute.justifyAlignment: Attribute.justifyAlignment.value!,
    };
```

What I'd like to do is only add the final `Attribute.justifyAlignment: Attribute.justifyAlignment.value!` only if `showJustify = true`

Is there a simply way to accomplish this?

I was thinking of only adding the first 3 to the original list and then doing

```
if (showJustify == true)
_valueToText.add(Attribute.justifyAlignment: Attribute.justifyAlignment.value!)
```

But maybe there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using [collection-if](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators). For example:

```dart
bool condition = true/false;
final map = <int, String>{
  0: 'Zero',
  if (condition) 1: 'One',
};
```

To answer your question:

```
final _valueToText = <Attribute, String>{
 Attribute.leftAlignment: Attribute.leftAlignment.value!,
 Attribute.centerAlignment: Attribute.centerAlignment.value!,
 Attribute.rightAlignment: Attribute.rightAlignment.value!,
 if (showJustifty) Attribute.justifyAlignment: Attribute.justifyAlignment.value!,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include the elements in a list in another list with `...` and since you can add a ternary condition to it, you can add those elements with the condition. Then you can generate the map from the list using `Map::fromIterable`. Like so:

```
final _valueToText = Map.fromIterable<Attribute, String>([
        Attribute.leftAlignment, 
        Attribute.centerAlignment, 
        Attribute.rightAlignment, 
        ...(showJustify
             ? 
            [Attribute.justifyAlignment] : []
        ),
    ], 
    key: (attr) => attr, 
    value: (attr) => attr.value!
);
```